# swift how to make ui label always 4 lines

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

This is my code

```
aboutMessageLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
//                .ByWordWrapping // or NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            aboutMessageLabel.numberOfLines = 4
            aboutMessageLabel.text = "bla bla"
```

where aboutmessageLabel is an instance of UILabel.

If my content is more than 4 lines, it shows just the first 4 lines and that is what I want.

However, if the content is less than 4 lines, it the height doesn't keep as the hieght for 4 lines, it becomes the hieght of the content.

is there anyway where i can always make the label 4 lines even if the content is less than 4 lines?

Comment: It seems like you're using the intrinsic size of the label in your constraints. You should set the label's height constraint to the height you want it to be to prevent resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of the label in the `MainStoryboard` (like in the 2nd image), then click on your label, then in the `Attributes Inspector` set the number or `Lines` to 4 like this:

[image]

Your label will have 4 lines, no matter who much text there is (which can be a bad thing as well if you have too much text like in the example):

[image]

Furthermore, did you should add constraints to the label. This will keep it the same size always. I'm assuming you want to create something like a meta description of a product, song, whatever. So if you keep the same size and have the 4 lines set, you'll be fine. It'll adjust based on the number of words while keeping the size. Edit the color of the label background to see the if it works/stays the same size when testing.

Comment: my text is dynamic, i set the number of lines 4 in the story boardand removed my code but stil with the problem

Comment: Did you adjust the size in the MainStoryBoard? Do you have enough text to fill up those 4 lines? Btw, edit the text in the Attributes Inspector and not in the VC itself. Like in the image.

Comment: i don't always have text enough for 4 lines, that is my problem in the first place, u got me ?

Comment: I see.... But regardless of how much text you have you need 4 lines, right? Even if it's 4 words? What if its 1 word?

Comment: Any luck? Furthermore, did you add constraints to the label? This will keep it as the same size always. I'm assuming you want to create something like a meta description of a product, song, whatever. So if you keep the same size and have the 4 lines set, you'll be fine. It'll adjust based on the # of words while keeping the size. Edit the color of the label background to see the tit works when testing. @sarah